# Executing jstack getting access denied

Tags: java, thread-dump, jstack

My application is running as a windows service.
When I try to take thread dump using below command from Cmd running as Administrator, I am getting access denied on a machine running on Windows 2016 server

```
"D:\myapp\jre\bin\java.exe" -classpath tools.jar sun.tools.jstack.JStack 2544 >log1.txt
```

Getting

> 2544: Access is denied

Similar command when I run on another machine running in Windows server 2012,it successfully captures thread dump.
And both of these services are running with Local system.

As I googled and found this issue could be due to the service running under Localsystem and the command prompt(which I am using to execute jstack) running under different process, I modified the service to log on as my user account and restarted the service, still getting access denied.

Also tried using PsExec using below command:

```
 psexec -s "D:\myapp\jre\bin\java.exe" -classpath tools.jar sun.tools.jstack.JStack 2544 >log1.txt.
```

I dont know why but I am getting

> Error: Could not find or load main class sun.tools.jstack.JStack.

(Just to add I am running this command from the same folder where tools.jar is residing.)

I seem to have been stuck at all places..Any help will me much appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason why you are **not** using the [jstack utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html)? Classes in the `sun` package are usually not accessible.

Comment: Machine where I need to run it has only jre for running myapp so cannot used jdk's jstack utility

Comment: You can run `jstack` utility on a JVM running on a different computer. The syntax is detailed on the link in my previous comment. Or is that also not an option? In any case, file `tools.jar` is **not** part of JRE. So how are you using it?